# Charging data from sqlite in html page (addon firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have an html page in my addon that I open like that :

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
    id: "mozilla-link",
    label: "Visit Mozilla",
    icon: {
        "16": "./icon-16.png",
        "32": "./icon-32.png",
        "64": "./icon-64.png"
    },
    onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
    var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
    tabs.open({
        url: self.data.url("panel.html"),
        inBackground: false
    });
}
```

That's working as well as expected, but now I want to load some data from a sqlite database.

I'm already using the database in the workflow of my module, like that:

```
var database = Services.dirsvc.get("ProfD", Ci.nsIFile);
database.append("searchEngines.sqlite");
dbConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(database);
var stmt = dbConn.createStatement("SELECT * FROM table;");
while (stmt.executeStep()) {
    engines[stmt.row.exp] = {b : stmt.row.b};
}
stmt.finalize();
```

Now I want to pass these information on my html page (through JQuery if possible).

I heard about the `.port.emit` thing, I think that what I have to use, but I don't understand how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `tabs.open` call, add a property `onReady` (there are a few other onEvents that will probably work) and make its value the following function:

```
onReady: function (tab) {
 var worker = tab.attach({
   contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-2.1.1.min.js"), self.data.url("panel.js")]
 });
 worker.port.emit("customEventName", "message");
 worker.port.on("otherCustomEventName", function (stringData) {
   // Whatever you want to do with string value stringData
 });
}
```

Use a variable from a (more) global context (`worker = ...` without the `var`) if you want to access `worker.port.emit` outside the function in the `onReady` property.  `worker.port.on` is persistent, so you shouldn't need to create any of those outside the function's scope.  On the content script side, use `self.port.emit("eventName", messageString)` and `self.port.on("mainScriptEventName", function (stringFromMainScript) {/* do whatever */})`.  SQLite queries will be done in the main script.